# Ceylon version 1.2 Format Command

Tags: ceylon

How can I fix that:

Command:

```
$ ceylon format source/com/example/helloworld/*
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ceylon.language.runtime_.getMaxArraySize()Lceylon/language/Integer;
        at ceylon.collection.Hashtable.<init>(Hashtable.ceylon:35)
        at ceylon.collection.Hashtable.<init>(Hashtable.ceylon)
        at ceylon.collection.HashMap.$default$hashtable(HashMap.ceylon:31)
        at ceylon.formatter.options.Spaces$cache_.<init>(IndentMode.ceylon:62)
        at ceylon.formatter.options.Spaces$cache_.<init>(IndentMode.ceylon)
        at ceylon.formatter.options.Spaces.<init>(IndentMode.ceylon:59)
        at ceylon.formatter.options.FormattingOptions.$default$indentMode(FormattingOptions_generated.ceylon:355)
        at ceylon.formatter.options.FormattingOptions.<init>(FormattingOptions_generated.ceylon)
        at ceylon.formatter.options.loadProfile_.loadProfile(profiles.ceylon:79)
        at ceylon.formatter.options.loadProfile_.loadProfile(profiles.ceylon)
        at ceylon.formatter.options.commandLineOptions_.commandLineOptions(formattingOptions.ceylon:125)
        at ceylon.formatter.options.commandLineOptions_.commandLineOptions(formattingOptions.ceylon)
            at ceylon.formatter.run_.run(run.ceylon:285)
   ...
```

I think I have to re-install the formatter. But which version?

For no reason the following command works:

`ceylon run ceylon.formatter source/com/example/helloworld/*.ceylon`

Where is the difference and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ceylon.language.runtime` used to be [implemented in hand-written Java code](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.language/blob/a02c660780f5de3b756e29e7a77b77f8fd573daa/runtime/ceylon/language/runtime_.java). In this code, `getMaxArraySize()` accidentally [returned `ceylon.language.Integer`](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.language/blob/a02c660780f5de3b756e29e7a77b77f8fd573daa/runtime/ceylon/language/runtime_.java#L56) when it should have returned `long`. This worked, but wasn’t quite correct.

Then, with native support in Ceylon 1.2, `runtime` (along with some other objects) were [rewritten](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.language/commit/a4615d4b53248084e56034f2a526e4bceeaee0c9) as native Ceylon code. Since this is converted to Java by the Ceylon compiler, the method now gets the correct return type, `long`. Newly compiled modules will now call this method, but code that was compiled against an old `ceylon.language` will still try to call a method returning `ceylon.language.Integer`, which leads to your `NoSuchMethodError`.

What’s happening here, it seems, is that `ceylon format` runs `ceylon.formatter/1.1.0`, which was compiled against `ceylon.language/1.1.0`, and now can’t run with `ceylon.language/1.2.0`. `ceylon run ceylon.formatter` probably runs `ceylon.formatter/1.2.0` for some reason, which works.

I’m not sure what you need to do to fix this. I changed the way the `ceylon format` plugin works [recently](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.formatter/commit/e5cba6af07efb986ce4925d7979f6b5da732cffe), so you probably need to delete the old `ceylon format` script (a `ceylon-format` or `ceylon-format.bat` file somewhere in `.ceylon/bin`, I believe). Hopefully the new one is already there, ready to take over.

Answer (score 3):

Try `ceylon plugin uninstall format` and see if that fixes things.

A second option would be to say `ceylon plugin install ceylon.formatter/1.2.0`

The reason why `ceylon format` doesn't work but `ceylon run` does is because your installed `ceylon format` will look for the hard-coded version `1.1` which isn't compatible anymore while `ceylon run` will look for any version that's compatible with the current Ceylon version you're using. (So it will find both 1.1.0 and 1.2.0 but it will discard 1.1.0 because it isn't compatible and therefore choose 1.2.0 automatically)